# Error trying to install tensorflow on Thonny IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, thonny

I am trying to install tensorflow on the Thonny IDE however I am getting this error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for tensorflow**

I am not sure what to do because I can install Keras fine.

Thanks.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thonny/EUuE2Nk7zDY

Comment: @ycao I have looked that that and it still doesnt work in the open shell.

Comment: Thonny IDE is only tool to edit code - try to install it normally with `pip install tensorflow` or `python -m pip install tensorflow`